# Unable to show todo List in Initial render in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux, redux-form

I am trying to build the todoList using react, redux, redux-form and firestore database, I am able to insert the todo inside the database using actions or action creator also, I am able to fetch the data store in database but I am unable to show data on the website when the user first visits the website, also when user add todo and submit the form the first todo item shows to me blank!. Can someone help me to tell what's wrong with my code?

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Container} from 'react-bootstrap'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import InputForm from './InputForm'
import Todo from './Todo'
import {listTodo} from '../actions' 




class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.renderList = this.renderList.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.listTodo();
        console.log(this.props.list);
    }

    renderList(){
        return this.props.list.map((todo,id) => {
            return (
                <Todo todo={todo} key={id}/>
            )
        })
    }

    render() {
        console.log("rendered");
        if(!this.props.list){
            return <div>Loading...</div>
        }
        return (
            <Container fluid>
                <h1 className="text-center" style={{marginTop: "5vh"}}>Todo App</h1>
                <InputForm />
                {this.renderList()}
            </Container>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state.todoList);
    return  {
        list: state.todoList
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {listTodo})(App)
```

Todo.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Card } from 'react-bootstrap'


class Todo extends React.Component {
    
    render(){
        console.log(this.props.todo);
        return (
            <Card className="text-center">
                <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Text>{this.props.todo.todo}</Card.Text>
                </Card.Body>
                <Card.Footer className="text-muted">DeadLine by {this.props.todo.date}</Card.Footer>
            </Card>
        )
    }
}

export default Todo
```

action(index.js)

```
import database from '../firebase/firebase'

export const addTodo = (inputValue) => {
    database.collection('Todo').add({
        todo: inputValue.todo_input,
        date: inputValue.todo_date
    });
    return {
        type: "ADD_TODO",
        payload: inputValue

    };
}

export const listTodo = () => {
    const data = [];
    database.collection('Todo').onSnapshot(snapshot => snapshot.docs.map(doc => data.push(doc.data())));
    return {
        type: 'LIST_TODO',
        payload: data
    }
}

export const deleteTodo = id => {
    //delete todo
    return {type: 'DELETE_TODO'}
}
```

TodoReducer.js

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TODO':
            return [...state, action.payload];
        case 'LIST_TODO':
            return action.payload;
        case 'DELETE_TODO':
            return state.filter(item => item.id !== action.payload);
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

reducers.js

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import {reducer as formReducer} from 'redux-form'
import todoReducer from './TodoReducer'

export default combineReducers({
    form: formReducer,
    todoList: todoReducer
});
```

Comment: I guess the first step is to check that `this.props.listTodo` is fetching (or otherwise loading) your todos list. Can you update your question to include your action creators, reducers, and any other code that affects the fetching/loading/rendering of todos (i.e. all relevant code)?

Comment: Agree, there is no mention of how the to-do list is fetched.
You should first display a placeholder/skeleton, then render the to-do list when the data is fetched from the server.

Comment: Are you running any asynchronous action middleware, i.e. something like Redux-Thunks? The data will be fetched/loaded asynchronously and your redux store needs to be able to handle asynchronous actions.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the help, I was confused in async await syntax but later on I had solve the issue

Comment: @ChiragLalwani are you saying the issue was the async syntax and that it is now solved? Or that you solved a specific error in the async syntax but the main problem persists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `listTodo` action creator, you create an object `data` and return that as part of your `LIST_TODO` action. This `data` object is then persisted into your store and **then** manipulated by your `onSnapshot` callback to add items to that data *after the fact*.
Those changes cannot be detected by React-Redux and so your component does not update by itself with content.

```js
export const listTodo = () => {
    const data = [];
    // do never do something like this!
    database.collection('Todo').onSnapshot(snapshot => snapshot.docs.map(doc => data.push(doc.data())));
    return {
        type: 'LIST_TODO',
        payload: data
    }
}
```

This breaks the second [Redux Principle](https://redux.js.org/understanding/thinking-in-redux/three-principles#state-is-read-only) "The only way to change the state is to emit an action, an object describing what happened".

To do something like this, you would need to use a middleware, most commonly the `redux-thunk` middleware.

That is already included in the official Redux Toolkit, which I would generally recommend you to check out.

Since showing you how to do this correctly would turn into a 1:1 copy of the official tutorials, check those out instead:

- for old-style "Vanilla Redux": [Redux Fundamentals, Part 6: Async Logic and Data Fetching](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic)
- for "Modern Redux" with Redux Toolkit: [Redux Essentials, Part 5: Async Logic and Data Fetching](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic)